# Jquery CSS thumbnails with hover state

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a slideshow with 6 thumbnails. The thumbnails have a CSS hover state.

Using JQuery, when the user selects the thumbnail, I would like the hover image to remain (so the user knows what thumbnail is selected).

When the user clicks on the second thumbnail, all the other thumbnails do not have a hover any more.

```
$('.thumb').click(function(){
    $(this).css('background-position-y', 'top').siblings(this).css('background-position-y', 'bottom');
});
```

Comment: can you show a sample of your html or create a fiddle maybe?

Comment: Here you are http://jsfiddle.net/ZVkpj/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Updated with user code from fiddle

---

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/RNYwG/1

---

Javascript:

```
$(function(){
    $('.thumb').click(function(){
       $('.thumb-hover').removeClass('thumb-hover');
       $(this).addClass('thumb-hover');
    });
});
```

---

CSS:

```
#thumbnails > .thumb{
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:0 -92px;
    border: 1px solid #999;
    margin: 10px 0 0 10px;
    padding: 0;
    width: 153px;
    height: 91px;
    float: left;
}
#thumbnails > .thumb-hover, .thumb:hover{
    background-position: 0 0;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

---

HTML:

```
<div id="thumbnails">
    <div class="thumb" style="background-image:url('images/slideshow/1_thumb.jpg');" onclick="mySwipe.slide(0, 700)"></div>
    <div class="thumb" style="background-image:url('images/slideshow/2_thumb.jpg');" onclick="mySwipe.slide(1, 700)"></div>
    <div class="thumb" style="background-image:url('images/slideshow/3_thumb.jpg');" onclick="mySwipe.slide(2, 700)"></div>
    <div class="thumb" style="background-image:url('images/slideshow/4_thumb.jpg');" onclick="mySwipe.slide(3, 700)"></div>
    <div class="thumb" style="background-image:url('images/slideshow/5_thumb.jpg');" onclick="mySwipe.slide(4, 700)"></div>
    <div class="thumb" style="background-image:url('images/slideshow/6_thumb.jpg');" onclick="mySwipe.slide(5, 700)"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In this example case where the thumbnails are siblings inside a parent:

```
<div>
   <div class="thumb"></div>
   <div class="thumb"></div>
   <div class="thumb"></div>
</div>
```

```
$('.thumb').click(function(){
    $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
});
```

Which means your CSS would look like:

```
.thumb{
/*   normal styles */
/*   you can use also CSS3 like: */
/*   transition: 0.2s;    */
}
.thumb.active{
/*    active styles (use !important if needed) */
}
```